Elementor loop grid's post taxonomy custom query not working
I am trying to display only the child terms on an archive page of a custom taxonomy's term called "verticals".
function filter_elementor_loop_widget_terms($query) {
    // Check if it's a taxonomy archive for 'verticals'
    if (is_tax('verticals')) {
        // Get the current term object
        $current_term = get_queried_object();

        // Get child terms of the current term
        $args = array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'verticals',
            'child_of'   => $current_term->term_id,
            'hide_empty' => false,  // Set to true if you want to hide empty terms
            'fields'     => 'ids', // We only need the IDs
        );

        $child_terms = get_terms($args);

        if (!empty($child_terms) && !is_wp_error($child_terms)) {
            // Modify the query to include only child terms
            $query->set('post_type', 'any'); // This ensures we're adding a tax_query and not replacing it
            $query->set('tax_query', array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'verticals',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => $child_terms,
                ),
            ));
        } else {
            // Ensure no results are returned if no child terms are found
            $query->set('tax_query', array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'verticals',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => array(0), // This ensures no results
                ),
            ));
        }
    }
}
add_action('elementor/query/child_verticals_terms', 'filter_elementor_loop_widget_terms');

This does not display anything at all. I have tried other options as well but no luck.
I even tried giving the query manual IDs for terms to display but that does not work either.
So I am assuming there is something wrong with the way I am trying to apply this hook.
Right below this book, I created another hook to filter posts by their title and it worked fine.

I've run into the same issue, this seems to be a bug in the current Elementor versions. Here's a GitHub post talking about the same issue: https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/27647.
Essentially, as soon as you enter any query ID into a taxonomy loop grid, it stops working. Even if that query ID is not even filtered in the code.
Luckily there's a workaround using the filter elementor/loop_taxonomy/args.
add_filter('elementor/loop_taxonomy/args', function(array $args): array
{
    return array_merge($args, [
        // any term query args
    ]);
});


Yes, I had to create a custom shortcode for this. I also created the GitHub thread you shared.
